# Mirror laptop to TV on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: screen

Is there any software available which casts laptop screen to a smart TV over Wifi? I can do so without issues on Windows using the inbuilt feature.

Comment: In my laptop with Ubuntu 20.04.x LTS I use an HDMI cable and get the internal monitor and the TV 'side by side'. With the touchpad I can drag a window from the internal monitor to the TV, make it fullscreen and enjoy. Someone else may have experience of using wifi for this purpose ...

Answer (score 1):

This is a cross-site duplicate of [How to connect to a wireless display (my Smart TV) with Linux Mint](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/312200/how-to-connect-to-a-wireless-display-my-smart-tv-with-linux-mint/). Check the answer there to do this with Gnome Network Displays, works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether issue has been resolved or not. In Ubuntu 20.04, one can open settings from the right of the top task bar and then go to Sharing.

```
Settings->Sharing->Screen Sharing
```

Comment: Nice, I never noticed this item.However, on my machine both "screen sharing" and "media sharing" are disabled without any way to enable it